SfRichTextBoxAdv table borders behave strangely when loading a file from XAML
If i try to save a document to xaml file and then without modifying it at all load it back into the SfRichTextBoxAdv then all the borders on all tables would disappear.
If after loading a xaml document i try to set the borders manually through the "Borders and shading" dialog then one of the following things happen:

Borders set to ALL: All of the borders are rendered, even the diagonals.
Borders set to BOX: Only the first column of the table have borders, and there are all of the borders, including the diagonals.
Borders set to NONE: The table have no borders, as expected.
Borders set to CUSTOM in any configuration: The table have no borders at all.

The MRE project is a plain MainWindow with a single SfRichTextBox inside of it, no code behind the UI.
Used packages: Syncfusion.SfRichTextBoxAdv.WPF:25.2.6 (latest version atm)
Details: Windows 7 x64, WPF Project (.NET Framework 4.8)

We have included the fix for the reported bug with “Table borders not preserved on loading XAML file” in our latest weekly NuGet release (v26.1.38).
Root cause of the issue:
The issue occurs because table cell values (border color, line style, line width) inherit from the "Table Grid" style instead of being directly assigned. When exporting to XAML, only directly set values are written. Since these values come from styles, they aren't included in the XAML, leading to missing borders upon reloading.
Please use the below link to download our latest weekly NuGet:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.SfRichTextBoxAdv.WPF/26.1.38
